# How to find the second image of a div class with the same name as the first one?

Tags: php, image, dom, find

There is this html page :

```
    Lundi 11h 
<img id="bull_98812001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j06.png"/><img id="bull_98803001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j11.png"/><img id="bull_98818001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j11.png"/><img id="bull_98809001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j11.png"/><img id="bull_98804001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j11.png"/><img id="bull_98830002" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j14.png"/><img id="bull_98814001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j10.png"/></div><div class="bulltimb">

                    mardi 11h
                    <img id="bull_98812001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j09.png"/><img id="bull_98803001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j10.png"/><img id="bull_98818001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j10.png"/><img id="bull_98809001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j10.png"/><img id="bull_98804001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j05.png"/><img id="bull_98830002" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j05.png"/><img id="bull_98814001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j14.png"/></div><div class="bulltimb">

                    mercredi 11h
                    <img id="bull_98812001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j01.png"/><img id="bull_98803001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j01.png"/><img id="bull_98818001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j04.png"/><img id="bull_98809001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j05.png"/><img id="bull_98804001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j04.png"/><img id="bull_98830002" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j05.png"/><img id="bull_98814001" class="bulltimbpic" src="/images/pictos/Pictos_Meteo_Nc_blanc/j05.png"/></div></div>
```

I would like to extract the 3 images with the id `bull_98818001`

I did, in my php page :

```
$image1 = $html->find('img[id="bull_98818001"]', 0) ->src;

echo $image1;
```

How can I find the 2nd and 3rd img `"bull_98818001"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the fastest and easiest way.

To find the next image with the same div class name :

```
$image2 = " image2 = ".$html->find('img[id="bull_98818001"]', 1) ->src;
```

just replace the `0` with `1`

Answer (score 2):

**For your information, you cannot get second class using php**

You can use attributes like *id, class, name, input[type]*,... using JQuery or JavaScript

To select the second element in your example you can write:

```
expand(wait:true)  { 
    $(".btn", 1);
}
```

You can also simply access an element using subscript operator:

```
expandOrderLink(wait:true)  { 
    $(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right")[1];
}
```

Comment: I've tried but the php is throwing an error.. Maybe I'm using it wront ?

Comment: Hi @Steph , you cannot use this script in php. Please try this in jquery.

Comment: Hi, Thx for your answer. I've never used Jquery. So basically I have to create an html page right ? But how can I link it with my php page and my code ?

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, you can't have the same id on the same html document.**

*The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).
The id value can be used by CSS and JavaScript to perform certain tasks for a unique element with the specified id value.*

If you want to get the attribue 'src' of all the images which has the **class="bulltimbpic"**, you should use jquery or pure javascript.

You can try this to get all the attribute src with class="bulltimbpic" listed in an array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var images = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bulltimbbloc .bulltimb").each(function(){
        images.push($(this).find('#bull_98812001').attr('src'));
    })
});

console.log(images);
</script>
```

Comment: The html document isn't mine. It's this website : http://www.meteo.nc/nouvelle-caledonie/previsions/bulletin   . I'll try your way and let you know

Comment: I have modified jquery so that you can extract the 3 images link with `id=bull_98812001` as it is on the website.